# How to duplicate output of process to file and console (in Kotlin program)

Tags: kotlin

I have a simple snippet of Kotlin code

```
import java.io.*
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit.MINUTES
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit


val proc = ProcessBuilder("C:\\tools\\build\\maven\\3.6.1\\bin\\mvn.cmd")
    .directory(null)
    .redirectOutput(ProcessBuilder.Redirect.PIPE)
    .redirectError(ProcessBuilder.Redirect.PIPE)
    .start()
println("Started")
proc.waitFor(60, TimeUnit.MINUTES)
println("Ended")
val output : String = proc.inputStream.bufferedReader().readText()
println("Output : " + output)
var log : File = File("cmd.log")
log.writeText(output)
```

This code run command then saves output in string then print output to console
But printing is occured when external program is completed.
My question is:
I would like to see program output in real time mode.
From other hands I would like to see output of external program while it works.
This code run as Kotlin script : kotlinc -script script.ktc

If place string

```
val output : String = proc.inputStream.bufferedReader().readText()
```

Before waitFor call. I observed that execution is blocked as expected

Answer (score 1):

I'm sorry for this question, it was quite simple,I found simple answer today.

```
val proc = ProcessBuilder("ls", "-lR", "c:\\toolchains")
    .directory(null)
    .redirectOutput(ProcessBuilder.Redirect.PIPE)
    .redirectError(ProcessBuilder.Redirect.PIPE)
    .start()
println("Started")
val output: BufferedReader = proc.inputStream.bufferedReader()
var line: String? = output.readLine()
val log: File = File("cmd.log")
while (line != null) {
    println("Next Line " + line)
    log.appendText(line.toString() + System.lineSeparator())
    line = output.readLine()
}

proc.waitFor(60, TimeUnit.MINUTES)
println("Ended")
```